# sed search and replace until it doesn't match anything

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've got a CSV file and there are column values like this "sdfsdafsdafsad\\\", and I need to do a search and replace for \" to " until there are no more \" values. Currently I'm just looping this command and then grepping to see if there are any other matching rows but I need an automated solution.

```
/usr/bin/sed -i.bak 's/\\\" / \"/g' *.txt
```

Is there an automated way to do this? It's be great if sed had some secret switch --do-until-no-more-matches but I haven't found that yet. This is running in a directory with a few hundred files and each file has up to 500k lines.

Comment: You want to remove however many \ characters there are before a double quote?

Comment: Ya, I need to remove all the \'s before a double quote.

Comment: Is `s/\\*"/"/g` what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of `s/\\*"/"/g` or `s/\\\+"/"/g` should do what you want with sed.